# Is there a way to pull orders (etc.) with href links already loaded bigcommerce api

Tags: api, bigcommerce

When I pull in resources and there is the linked resources (eg. Products have images) then it seems you must do another call to the api rather than just walk into the child nodes (eg. product categories). The downside of doing this is speed - It is slow to call the API multiple times for one product / order etc.

Does anyone have an approach which pre-loads the links or speeds up the calls?

Answer (score 0):

David, currently none. Unfortunately you need to make multiple API calls to get the sub resources, but from what I understand, that will change in future.